# How to ColdFusion plugin in Eclipse IDE

Tags: coldfusion, eclipse-plugin

Hi I'm trying to install ColdFusion plugin in Eclipse IDE. But in the Eclipse Marketplace ColdFusion is not present. So what to do in order to install the ColdFusion plugin..?

Comment: Did you search the marketplace for CFEclipse? It ought to show up. If not, there's manual install instructions here: http://trac.cfeclipse.org/wiki/InstallingCfeclipse

Comment: @barnyr - Haha, I see we are thinking along the same lines.

Comment: Are you searching for the Adobe ColdFusion IDE? You'll have to eventually pay for that. CFEclipse is the free IDE. I'm not sure where support for it is, but thousands of us use it.

Answer (score 3):

I found it by doing a search on [CFEclipse](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/cfeclipse). You can also download it from [cfclipse.org](http://cfeclipse.org/index.cfm/download/)

Answer (score 2):

Download ColdFusion Builder, you can install it as a standalone IDE or as a plugin to your existing Eclipse installation.